# Getting "__callStatic is not called", how can I call static?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

Code:

```
class m
{
  public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
  {
      echo "Calling static method '$name' "
           . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
  }
}

class MethodTest extends m
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        echo "Calling object method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }
}

class MethodTest2 extends m
{
    public function index()
    {
      MethodTest::test();
    }


}
call_user_func(['MethodTest2','index']);
```

Error:

> Strict Standards: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method MethodTest2::index() should not be called statically in /var/www/html/api/index.php on line 45
>   Calling static method 'test'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this out: [overloading](https://www.php.net/language.oop5.overloading)

> The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that **have not been declared** or are **not visible** in the **current scope**.
>
> `__callStatic()` is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods **in a static context**.

You are calling the **non-static method statically**, the method has already **been declared** but **not static** in current scope.

`__callStatic` only works for **methods not yet defined**.

So if you try this will work:

```php
$test2 = new MethodTest2();
call_user_func([$test2,'index']);
// => Calling static method 'test'
// Because $test2 calling index() method, and then MethodTest calling test() method which doesn't exist.
```